# ZIP file decoding

Tags: c#, string, zip, decode

I get a ZIP archive file as encoded string from third party.
It contains hierarchy of webapp files (html, css, js).

The archive encoded string fragment looks like this:

```
PK1S�Qview/PKPK1S�Q view\css/PKPK1S�Qview\css\styles.css�WKo�8>o���E�6K�|Kr�C�X ��
��K!˴-T�I~$E���e���6���p�rf8���f7�ׯ��)�����Y�.�YD��G6uW�E
�)���;�1�z��"E=��E�͍c���wų�E�{fnj�=��,�k��DQ�U�L[�<��j�=�\3�r+qm�i���η�To����x�&[�v��-������X��E黱6a^�z�����M_7�H��f�<��Eה�SՕ    ⇽_۾��ndX�wg۾���|�1�`6 M`��-竴ؙ��<�@d��/$�8?Zs�M�po��ڙ��[�.Mt�PY���.Y��i�Q�#��pn�-�E��΅�5��������?�v���=���[P ��f������,U��Xd��u[o�%.�ٳhۖ��,�>���i�[�yx,�;1�nݪ��l���M���������SJ-�$�f�W}��ЈF�q��D����=
?x'���X�N>�e�3M�o"��ĕFB��G)IY��$i�XBb���$fqI��X*B�D@A9�9Iy��$Dp��"���BǄ�8ǊH����d�K?�����yL�L
E\����"B���?Ӕ0�x�3A�B��T �� -K��D�;��{h(�3ǚKI�ή-;��LI�r�@v�1����P;؉x�PPER�"VP4���T�y$�������Ќ��v�a�.�S� cX"i�Ph7�郖9�h,7�I���8@D)�H��Tl1X+1 �]4��H�7��N���3���/ld�L��K��,ǻkxR��V;.�%@�Z��N�
�)�@��P��t�8`�Xiq���Up��i�|�1��K3��N��zX\ÑBl�9&���$V7$R���A�{{�(��$HH1� ��`�5�?��R�Phh�3����p����Pٝ�Թ��}
W%�^�r������ ��JG}_�;w���@������]���{��x�fGtJ��-#fW$�Q�J��Gk��A�k������B��=z���E�lMc��f�нX?y<$��j�^�ɷi��J�jU�����r��z~\rяٰkl~��i�-Jcs�嗳�v��(����z�%���h�Ҕ�7�:cl��.�v�7�O���]�����zk��Yg +n�3���_���0�&.1ͳ&�
�_�~�dv/|�F��4��U ��&�Sh/'�T
```

...etc.

How can I decode this string back to normal ZIP-file?
I should do it programmatically in .NET Framework 3.5 C# code, but I would like to know at least general decoding algorithm.

Thank you!

Comment: Also this article: [Zip and unzip a string of data in memory](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2017/12/20/zip-and-unzip-a-string-of-data-in-memory/)

Comment: Why are we using .NET Framework 3.5 again? there has been about 15+ version after it

Comment: @the-general I can't do something about it. I develop app for very old type of devices (WinCE 5.0)